# Java Spring - use @ to encode characters at a URL endpoint

Tags: java, spring

I have an application that uses Java Spring with REST endpoints.  One of the endpoints we have is a GET call that searches our DB for URLs, so the spring code would look something like:

```
@GET
@Path("/search/{type}/{value}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@ValidateRequest
@ApiOperation(value = "searchByTypeValue", nickname = "searchByTypeValue")
@ApiResponses(value = {
        @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Success", response = returnObject.class),
        @ApiResponse(code = 401, message = "Unauthorized"),
        @ApiResponse(code = 403, message = "Forbidden"),
        @ApiResponse(code = 404, message = "Not Found"),
        @ApiResponse(code = 500, message = "Failure")})

public @ResponseBody
    @Valid ArrayList<ReturnObjectVO> searchByTypeValue(
            @PathParam("type") String searchType,
            @PathParam("value") String searchValue){

        //do stuff
      }
```

This is a universal search based on what they want to search, so they select their search type, and then type in what to search.  So if they want to search by ID, their resulting URL would look like: `https://my.app.com/rest/search/Id/26816931`.  Now, we let the user search by a URL as well, including `https://`.  To solve the issue of having `/` in the endpoint, we encode `/` as `@` before sending it to the server, so if the user searches by `http://my.otherApp.com`, the URL would look like `https://my.app.com/rest/search/appURL/http:@@my.otherApp.com`.  However, this is causing a 400 error, and I know it is coming from http://, since if I remove that, we are able to search based on our matching algorithm.  However, we might have a case where there is `http://my.otherApp.com` and `https://my.otherApp.com`, so we want to include that part.  Are you allowed to put the `@` symbol like that?

Comment: You're allowed to put both `/` and `@` in the URL, you just need to **encode** them. `http://my.otherApp.com` --> `http%3A%2F%2Fmy.otherApp.com`, and `http:@@my.otherApp.com` --> `http%3A%40%40my.otherApp.com`

Comment: Use [URL encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) which is the standard way to escape characters in a URL instead of inventing your own scheme. Java even has standard classes for this, see [`java.net.URLEncoder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/net/URLEncoder.html).

Answer (score 0):

base64 encode the url before appending

Comment: Would I need to decode on the backend, or is that automatic?

Comment: when you check the `type` you would see it's url and then would decode the last path segment as the string of the url. but you should also be able to URL encode them. base64 just seems to be an easy way to not have problematic chars in the string.